# IBM db2, transactions in SQL-Scripts

Tags: transactions, db2, ibm-midrange

I am searching for an option to operate with transactions in the IBM SQL-Scripts program.
For comparison purposes, i added an image on what SQL-Scripts-Program i am talking about.

[image]

Further, I also want to achieve those transactions programmatically with RPG(free). How could this look like?

Comment: As it stands, the answer to this question is a whole book. Please refine your question to a single specific question that can be answered in a single page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mention both the Run SQL Scripts utility, and RPG.

You've got basically two choices in either place.

1. Change the default isolation level
2. Add the `with` clause to individual statements to override the default.

For Run SQL Scripts, the default is configured in the JDBC connection.
[image]

For SQLRPGLE, the default can be set

- During compile, via the `COMMIT()` parameter of the `CRTSQLRPGI` command
- by using the `SET OPION` SQL statement in your source

`SET OPTION` is preferred, unless you have a CMS that can ensure the CRTSQLRPGI command is always issued properly.

```
exec SQL
 set option commit = *CHG;
```

Note that the `SET OPTION` statement is a compile time, not run-time statement.  It must be the physically first SQL statement in your SQLRPGLE module.  You can only have one and it is in effect for the entire module.

Regardless of the default isolation/commitment level in effect.  You can set the level for a given statement using the `WITH` clause.

```
update mytable
  set mycolumn = 1
  with chg;
```

Lastly, note that in order to use commitment control, your table will have to be journaled.

Comment: Right now I'm just figuring out how this all works. How would a SQL's look like if i want to make just those three things:
a) Update a table, and check how much rows are affected, with No Commit (would that be "with nc"? My SQL-Scripts keeps on hanging if i execute an sql with this suffix)
b) Select the table, and watch that there are effectively no rows changed, because no commit has been executed.
c) commit the change / or rollback.
Can you write a fiew example SQL's for that kind of application?

Answer (score 1):

See the [*compound (dynamic)*](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_72/db2/rbafzcompounddynstmt.htm) statement

Note that you will need to use a statement terminator other than `;` in your SQL Editor. `@` is a commonly used one.
Also if you use IBM Data Studio you will get local syntax parsing which will help you spot any syntax errors in your code.